# How do I make a WebView transparent?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Consider the following QML snippet:

```
Page {
    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

I then attempt to load some HTML in the WebView using the following JavaScript:

```
webView.loadHtml('<b>test</b>');
```

However, the WebView has a white background:

[image]

(Ignore the fact that the text is too small.)

Is there a way to make the background transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try QtWebKit.experimental. If you add import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0 to your QML files, your WebView objects will have access to experimental attributes:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1


MainView {
    id: main
    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        id: mypage
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            anchors.fill: mypage
            WebView {
                id: webView
                anchors.fill: parent
                experimental.transparentBackground: true
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: webView.loadHtml("<p>Hello</p>");
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll get this kind of warning:

> WARNING: The experimental API will change from version to version, or
>   even be removed. You have been warned!

Comment: Thanks. Are there any implications of using an older version of QtWebKit? (The latest version is 3.0.)

Comment: You can use both at the same time, import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0 AND import QtWebKit 3.0